# Migrate from WordPress (with buddypress plugin)

Tags: 7, migrations

I have a Wordpress 3.2.1 site with many users, and BuddyPress plugin installed. I want to move all the users and profile fields, the BuddyPress comments, and the blog content into a fresh Drupal 7 website.

What is the easiest, or best way to do this?

Comment: Wordpress allows you to export a feeds file xml, rss etc. I would then use that file and map it to the appropriate drupal fields with the Drupal Feeds Module.

Comment: wordpress only gives me one export format and that is XML, but feeds module only accepts CSV file. should i convert that into CSV?

Comment: Hi there, I used the feed module and i now have one issue, my the password field in feeds says "unencrypted password", how do i import all the password from wordpress into my drupal 7 ?? i dont think decrypting the pasword is possible at this point!

Answer (score 5):

I did a Wordpress import this summer into a Drupal 6 system.  While I ended up doing a manual import for a variety of reasons, a decent amount of my code was based on [Wordpress Import](http://drupal.org/project/wordpress_import).

This module has been suplamented by [Wordpress Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/wordpress_migrate) which uses the [Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) framework.  Since you mentioned Drupal 7, this approach would be worth exploring.

Both of these use the WXR format, so you are likely to lose less data than with other methods, and you can generate the backup file right from the WP admin interface.

Personally, I would take a backup of your site (like with [Backup and Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate)), and try out Wordpress Migrate before trying to use [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds).

Keep in mind that Wordpress RSS and WXR files may not always be valid XML, so you may run into parsing issues.  I have had problems because of WP plugins that add embed code or `<script>` blocks directly into the post/page, and then WP doesn't wrap everything properly in a CDATA section.

It is also worth noting that you may end up losing any markup that would be the result of short-tags in the post/page body, and just import the sort-tag.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable information. I did use migrate as my first approach before i create this post, however, my main issue is to get my Wordpress Buddypress plugin information into drupal. i used buddypress to create profile fields in wordpress and now im stuck in migrating everything into the drupal site. thats again for all the help. please let me know if you have any ideas as to how to get these contents migrated.

Comment: Not sure about that part.  I would tackle this with a custom import script, but I write these all the time.

Comment: So you think i should edit the default wordpress export script maybe?? or work on a drupal custom import script?

Comment: Without knowing much about BuddyPress, I don't know what to say.  You may try cloning the WP Import module as a starting point.  I do lots of custom import scripts, but I also have lots of custom import scripts to use as starting points.

Comment: Hi there, I used the feed module and i now have one issue, my the password field in feeds says "unencrypted password", how do i import all the password from wordpress into my drupal 7 ?? i dont think decrypting the pasword is possible at this point!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look at the [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module, which I have used to migrate from a Silverstripe installation to Drupal.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, i did look into the feeds module and there is also Migrate module as well, however my question is to how i get all those content into a XML, CVS, or any type of export file? For example, how do i get all my users with their buddypress profile fields along with my worpress export file? Thanks for all the help

Comment: Create a database dump in CVS format. This is easy using perhaps phpMyAdmin

Comment: thats is a great idea.. thank you. ill try that now and update you.

Comment: I tried the feed module, however this need to have seperate CSV files and that is very time consuming and also impossible because i can export both users and user field into one CSV files. any other ideas?

Comment: Hi there, I used the feed module and i now have one issue, my the password field in feeds says "unencrypted password", how do i import all the password from wordpress into my drupal 7 ?? i dont think decrypting the pasword is possible at this point!

Comment: @alex, did you solve the problem with the user passwords? As I understand it the password hashes is saved in the database and you need to use unencrypted passwords with feeds or else the hashes will be "re-hashed" during import. One solution would be to exclude the passwords in the import and then import the hashes using a `phpMyAdmin` (don't know if this will work but it's worth a try)

Answer (score 0):

Just a caveat. I haven't actually had any experience doing this. I'm just googling and researching. Looks like you should check out the [Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) module.

My first instincts of using the feeds module may be misguided.

Installing the [Wordpress Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/wordpress_migrate) module along side with the Migrate module seems to be your best bet as proscribed here: http://drupal.org/node/43178

Comment: Moving the content such as post into drupal is a fairly easy job, however having a plugin like buddypress in the wordpress adds profile fields in the wp site, and what im trying to do is to have all of that moved into my drupal site including the buddypress profile fields. any ideas??